# How can I access to a ServerControl exists inside an ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have the following `ListView`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="procedureTicketList" runat="server" ...
     <ItemTemplate> 
          <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runa...
```

How can I access to `MyGridView` programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code snippet.

```
protected void procedureTicketList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          GridView gv= ((GridView)e.Item.FindControl("MyGridView"));
         .
         .
         .

       }
```

**EDIT:**

Check the following code snippet.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="_simpleTableListView" OnItemDataBound="_simpleTableListView_ItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                ID
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Title
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("ID") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# Eval("title") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server">
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _simpleTableListView.DataSource = new Movie().GetAll;
        _simpleTableListView.DataBind();

    }

    protected void _simpleTableListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv= ((GridView)e.Item.FindControl("MyGridView"));

    }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Movie> GetAll
    {

        get
        {
            return new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie{Id=1,Title="A"},
                new Movie{Id=2,Title="B"},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) method.